# python twisted cred use

Tags: python, twisted

i am having a small doubt here regarding twisted for ex when i was browsing throug examples of twisted( which are very well written) i saw an example of using `cred`. i have to mention that this curiosity is because the more i use twisted ,more i am liking it and trying to wrap my head around it and understand its functionality in detail . now my question is **why in the first place i would use `cred`? if it is for simple user pass credentials cant a simple check to database can be used like its done in most web applications?** if it for making async then couldnt async version of db clients be used to achieve the same ?what benefits do i get by using `relam` , `avatars` and `portals`? i mean in which scenario these things could be used. I know it has something to do with my undersatnding of twisted cred so please help.  below is the ex i am talking about

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
from zope.interface import implementer, Interface

from twisted.protocols import basic
from twisted.internet import protocol
from twisted.python import log

from twisted.cred import error
from twisted.cred import portal
from twisted.cred import checkers
from twisted.cred import credentials

class IProtocolUser(Interface):
    def getPrivileges():
        """Return a list of privileges this user has."""

    def logout():
        """Cleanup per-login resources allocated to this avatar"""

@implementer(IProtocolUser)
class AnonymousUser:
    def getPrivileges(self):
        return [1, 2, 3]

    def logout(self):
        print("Cleaning up anonymous user resources")

@implementer(IProtocolUser)
class RegularUser:
    def getPrivileges(self):
        return [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]

    def logout(self):
        print("Cleaning up regular user resources")

@implementer(IProtocolUser)
class Administrator:
    def getPrivileges(self):
        return range(50)

    def logout(self):
        print("Cleaning up administrator resources")

class Protocol(basic.LineReceiver):
    user = None
    portal = None
    avatar = None
    logout = None

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendLine("Login with USER <name> followed by PASS <password> or ANON")
        self.sendLine("Check privileges with PRIVS")

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        if self.logout:
            self.logout()
            self.avatar = None
            self.logout = None

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        f = getattr(self, 'cmd_' + line.upper().split()[0])
        if f:
            try:
                f(*line.split()[1:])
            except TypeError:
                self.sendLine("Wrong number of arguments.")
            except:
                self.sendLine("Server error (probably your fault)")

    def cmd_ANON(self):
        if self.portal:
            self.portal.login(credentials.Anonymous(), None, IProtocolUser
                ).addCallbacks(self._cbLogin, self._ebLogin
                )
        else:
            self.sendLine("DENIED")

    def cmd_USER(self, name):
        self.user = name
        self.sendLine("Alright.  Now PASS?")

    def cmd_PASS(self, password):
        if not self.user:
            self.sendLine("USER required before PASS")
        else:
            if self.portal:
                self.portal.login(
                    credentials.UsernamePassword(self.user, password),
                    None,
                    IProtocolUser
                ).addCallbacks(self._cbLogin, self._ebLogin
                )
            else:
                self.sendLine("DENIED")

    def cmd_PRIVS(self):
        self.sendLine("You have the following privileges: ")
        self.sendLine(" ".join(map(str, self.avatar.getPrivileges())))

    def _cbLogin(self, result):
        (interface, avatar, logout) = result
        assert interface is IProtocolUser
        self.avatar = avatar
        self.logout = logout
        self.sendLine("Login successful.  Available commands: PRIVS")

    def _ebLogin(self, failure):
        failure.trap(error.UnauthorizedLogin)
        self.sendLine("Login denied!  Go away.")

class ServerFactory(protocol.ServerFactory):
    protocol = Protocol

    def __init__(self, portal):
        self.portal = portal

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        p = protocol.ServerFactory.buildProtocol(self, addr)
        p.portal = self.portal
        return p

@implementer(portal.IRealm)
class Realm:
    def requestAvatar(self, avatarId, mind, *interfaces):
        if IProtocolUser in interfaces:
            if avatarId == checkers.ANONYMOUS:
                av = AnonymousUser()
            elif avatarId.isupper():
                # Capitalized usernames are administrators.
                av = Administrator()
            else:
                av = RegularUser()
            return IProtocolUser, av, av.logout
        raise NotImplementedError("Only IProtocolUser interface is supported by this realm")

def main():
    r = Realm()
    p = portal.Portal(r)
    c = checkers.InMemoryUsernamePasswordDatabaseDontUse()
    c.addUser("auser", "thepass")
    c.addUser("SECONDUSER", "secret")
    p.registerChecker(c)
    p.registerChecker(checkers.AllowAnonymousAccess())

    f = ServerFactory(p)

    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

    from twisted.internet import reactor
    reactor.listenTCP(4738, f)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`twisted.cred` provides an abstraction which allows your application to be developed independent of the specific means of validation some credentials and lets your credentials database be developed independent of your application.

In your example, note how your application code (`Protocol`) is unaware of the fact that credentials are stored purely in memory.  It would likewise be unaware if you replaced `InMemoryUsernamePasswordDatabaseDontUse` with a PAM backend, an `/etc-passwd`-style database, or something using PostgreSQL.

Furthermore, those username/password backends can all be developed independently of your application logic - allowing each of your applications to re-use them, whether they are your work or work someone else has shared with you.

Comment: thanks for replying but it is still not clear to me i mean i can get that sort of abstraction using a class which checks for user validation ( suppose i am making a web app). is this not a suitable thing for a web app ?

Comment: I don't really understand.  Can you implement something equivalent to twisted.cred from scratch?  Of course you can.  twisted.cred is just a pile of Python code.  You could also implement your own HTTP server and your own filesystem and your own TCP/IP stack.  It's all just more software.  The point of libraries is so that not everyone has to re-implement every thing for every program.

Comment: i didn't mean that. i know libraries exist for some reason that is why in my question above i mentioned `I know it has something to do with my undersatnding of twisted cred` . if possible can you please provide me some directions over where i can look for more info on `twisted.cred` maybe then i will get it

Comment: Sorry, I still don't really understand what you're asking.  I assume you've read the twisted.cred docs on twistedmatrix.com?